# Targeting with Google Apps Script for Google Ads Performance Max Campaign

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, targeting

I'd like to get the number of click for each campaign on my account. For display campaign, I use the AdsApp.campaigns collection, and then call the targeting function for each campaign. It works fine.

But pour Performance Max Campaign, I see in the documentation that there is no targeting function for item in AdsApp.performanceMaxCampaign. I can just call the getStatsFor function for the campaign, not for each zone. Is there a way to do something similar to the classic campaign ?

Thanks for your help

Vincent